# Pass command into child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send control key to my child process but nothing happens. What I do wrong or don't understand?

```
var cp = require('child_process');

var child = cp.spawn('mpg123', ['test.mp3']);

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

setTimeout(function() {
    child.stdin.write('q\n');
    child.stdin.end();
}, 1500)
```

Comment: I am not able to install `mpg123` but when do the same with `vim` it works. Did you try to run manually `mpg123 test.mp3` and type `q`? Did it exit?

Comment: @FreeLightman yes it works in CLI

Comment: You can also try to check it with `vim`. Just write `var child = cp.spawn('vim', ['test.mp3']);`. **Note**: vim should be installed. Let me know if it works

Comment: @FreeLightman
Result:
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished

Comment: Can you tell your node version?